# Rails 3 rspec + capybara - current_path is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I have this in my users_spec.rb

```
  scenario "Go to contact page" do
    visit "/contact"
    current_path.should == contact_path
  end
```

After running rspec, I get

```
Failure/Error: current_path.should == contact_path
       expected: "/contact"
            got: nil (using ==)
```

For some reason, current_path seem to be returning nil. Is there a configuration that I am missing?

Comment: It turns out that because webrat is also included, there was some sort of conflict. I commented out my `webrat` from my gem file (which I wasn't using anyway). It was included earlier for some other testing (and also due to many outdated tutorials out there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Authors answer:**

[Min Ming Lo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/994471/min-ming-lo)

> It turns out that because webrat is also included, there was some sort
>   of conflict. I commented out my webrat from my gem file (which I
>   wasn't using anyway). It was included earlier for some other testing
>   (and also due to many outdated tutorials out there).