# Capybara visit not working

Tags: selenium, capybara, bdd, rspec2

ok I not sure what I am missing on the setting up of capybara, but on testing the visit link would appear not to be working.  so I have a 3.2 app, I have my specs_helper set up like so:

```
require "spork"

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'factory_girl'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'capybara/rails'

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium

  Capybara.default_wait_time = 5

  include Devise::TestHelpers # see spec/support/devise.rb
include CarrierWave::Test::Matchers
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
include New_spec_helpers

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
  RSpec.configure do |config|

    config.mock_with :rspec


    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false


   config.before :each do


       Capybara.default_selector = :css
      if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
      else
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      end
      DatabaseCleaner.start


    end

    config.after do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
  end

end

Spork.each_run do
  FactoryGirl.factories.clear
  FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence(:code) { |n| "code#{n}" }
    sequence(:title) { |n| "title#{n}" }
  end

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/factories/**/*.rb")].each{|f| load f}
  PortfolioNew::Application.reload_routes!
end
```

Then my test set up like this:

```
  before(:each) do
    build_projects
    visit(projects_path)
  end

  it "test js" , :js=>true do
    current_path.should == projects_path
  end
```

However all i get in return is this:

```
Failure/Error: current_path.should == projects_path
       expected: "/projects"
            got: nil (using ==)
```

i have checked my routes and the projects path is definitely correct and working.   Any thoughts on what the issue is would be gratefully received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the issue in a comment on the this similar post [Rails 3 rspec + capybara - current_path is nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382252/rails-3-rspec-capybara-current-path-is-nil)

Turns out the webrat conflicts with Capybara which was left in when from old tests.

So for anyone interested I just commented out of my gemfile and all good!

Comment: Glad you managed to solve the problem! The webrat/capybara thing can be a real pain...

Comment: Cheers it was driving me nuts! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `visit` call into the `it` block:

```
before(:each) do
  build_projects
end

it "test js" , :js=>true do
  visit(projects_path)
  current_path.should == projects_path
end
```

Comment: no same response, thanks for the feed back any other thoughts?